# Does this code ungetch() '\n'?

Tags: c

I searched everywhere, but I cannot find the answer to this! I'm working on the exercise from the K&R C books with a function they call getop. When I input for example 123, the code checks each element of input, and stops when it is not a digit. In this example it is '\n'; does it ungetch( '\n' )?

```
int getop(char s[])
{
    int i, c;

    while ((s[0] = c = getch()) == ' ' || c == '\t')
        ;
    s[1] = '\0';
    if (!isdigit(c) && c != '.')
        return c; /* not a number */
    i = 0;
    if (isdigit(c)) /*collect integer part*/
        while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))
            ;
    if (c == '.') /*collect fraction part*/
        while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))
            ;
    s[i] = '\0';
    if (c != EOF)
        ungetch(c);
    return NUMBER;
}
```

ungetch function:

```
void ungetch(int c) {
    if(bufp < MAXBUF) {
        printf("ungetch has been called\n");
        buf[bufp++] = c;
    }   
    else 
        printf("the buffer is full\n");
}
```

Comment: The condition for the `ungetch` line is `if (c != EOF)`. Ask yourself, if `c == '\n'`, is this condition `true` or `false`?

Comment: I thought that eof is for window ctrl+z , and '\n' is something else...?

Comment: EOF is the end of the file. It is not a character.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought that eof is for window ctrl+z , and '\n' is something
>   else...?

**ISO/IEC 9899**, **Programming languages — C**:

> `EOF` ... expands to an integer constant expression, with type int and
>   a negative value, that is returned by several functions to indicate
>   end-of-file, that is, no more input from a stream

Ctrl-Z on Windows is an input key combination that causes no more characters to be returned, not even the character equivalent of Ctrl-Z (0x1A).

> `\n` (*new line*) Moves the active position to the initial position of the
>   next line.

As to the original question: Since the negative value `EOF` is different from any `(unsigned char)` value, yes, this code does ungetch() `'\n'`.